# Make beam/dataflow Create.of(List<String>) node emit exactly the number of elements in the list

Tags: duplicates, google-cloud-dataflow, equals, apache-beam

My beam/dataflow job starts with a single static entry passed in like this:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection<String> initValue = p.apply(Create.of("MyStringValue"));
```

However when I run it (on DataflowRunner), the Create node produced by that statement emits multiple values. The longer I wait, the more times it emits the single value:

[image: Triplicate Create.of element]

This doesn't appear to be an artefact as later in the pipeline I get duplicate/triplicate/.. elements. Beam also logs a warning:

```
Can't verify serialized elements of type BoundedSource have well defined equals method. This may produce incorrect results on some PipelineRunner
```

How do I make my Create.of with one value emit just one value to the pipeline?
Do I need to attach an equals method or point it towards the equals method for String values (if so, how)!?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the usecase and what you are trying to solve with beam?

Comment: Well it should allow me to start the pipeline with a single value regardless, but the full story is that I want to run the com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery.query(QueryJobConfiguration) method. I want to return a sorted query from BigQuery. The provided BigQueryIO class will not sort with more than approx. 1 million rows of my data (I have an open support call regarding this). However the method above appears to do this. I need to inject something at the top to start it off, for instance the query itself or a parameter for it.

Comment: A little puzzled by the fuzed steps which has two Read(CreateSource) +unbounded adaptor. could you share a little more of the top of your pipeline please.  

Also please note that there is no guarantee of order in a Beam pipeline, so while the SQL statement will get back results ordered that order will not be preserved. This will be true for both BigQueryIO and output from a DoFn where you may manually read the SQL.  If using ordinal number within a single DoFn while you page through the results then that would work. But it would be a single thread processing all the 1M rows.

Comment: Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

Comment: And then PCollection<String> initValue = p.apply(Create.of("MyStringValue"));

Comment: I also tried with Create.timestamped(TimestampedValue.of(..)) which gives an output collection named something like "Create.TimestampedValues/ParDo(ConvertTimestamps).out0", but it still emits the single PCollection value multiple times (I find Beam/Dataflow is good at creating dupes when used by beginners :) ). I am fine trying this in a single thread to start with - could you elaborate on what you mean with ordinal numbers within a single DoFn? Thank you.

Comment: May you update the question adding your code, the existing output and what is the desired output? It's a little tricky to understand what is the problem by the description.

Comment: I have added the way I set up the pipeline. The desired output at that point in the pipeline is a single element (what I put into the pipeline). Not the same element a seemingly unbounded number of times.

Comment: Sometimes there are control elements added by some IOs. Can. you add a ParDo downstream of your Create.Og and observe the element counts on those? Does this always happen? Since this is a streaming pipeline the Elements added are only "(approximate)" as indicated by the table, and can have extra counts if there are retries. All streaming counters will have these issues, so please don't use them in a way expecting exact correctness. If you run the same pipeline in Batch, does it still count 3 instead of 1?